# Laboratory second-in-command aggressive towards me

Tags: interpersonal-issues

I am a Ph.D. student on a student residence permit in Germany, currently in the middle of my second year (out of three, but the project may be extended).

There's a woman in the laboratory who gradually became more and more aggressive towards me, screaming at me and banging things against the table when I made mistakes. **ETA**: I have not observed her attacking anyone else, so either she is good at being alone with her victims, or I somehow present a special interest for her.

Around a year ago I tried to have a talk with her; since she doesn't speak English well and my German was only A1 at the moment, I asked my effective supervisor (the laboratory head) to translate, which he did. This seemed to help for a while: we were able to interact in a solidly professional manner for some months. Interaction with her is unavoidable, by the way, since she's responsible for ordering all the chemicals and she knows where everything is stored.

A few days ago the problem returned: she started by making nasty remarks about my underperformance and underattendance and described my experiment as "hopelessly contaminated" (despite my supervisor later agreeing that the levels of contamination were well within acceptable limits). Yesterday she screamed at me for using the wrong kind of qPCR plate, took it from under my hands and threw it in the trash bin despite most of the plate having been taped off (as customarily done in the lab) and available for reuse. When asked why and to stop screaming, she cited lack of time.

My supervisor, when contacted about the incident, told me that he "understands her", since the plates are expensive. I am not handling this well. What should I do?

**ETA**:

Should I start walking around with dictaphone running? Last time I tried it, we've already had the talk and she stopped attacking me, so I didn't get any useful evidence. My supervisor "knows" that she attacks me, but there is no paper trail. (yet?) And even if I get any evidence, who should I submit it to? My supervisor, again, hoping that he'd understand me this time? Someone higher up the chain? Even then, what should I be hoping for, with that evidence? Getting her fired (which I don't find desirable or expect to be possible in the first place) would certainly be a pyrrhic victory, making my supervisor want to dispose of me -- and he'd find a way.

Should I try to leave the place (as recommended by [Sutton, 2017](https://www.bobsutton.net/book/asshole-survival-guide/))? As an international student on a residence permit, I can always go home, but that would wreck me psychologically. Is it even possible to change labs for an international student on a government stipend in Germany?

Comment: It sounds like you are being mistreated.  I suspect this person's behavior is not specific to you.  Managing aggressive behavior is the responsibility of the aggressive person's supervisor.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The problem with that is also that that woman is my superior and much older. She doesn’t have a supervisor as such; she just works in the lab where my supervisor is head.

Comment: The key is your supervisor is _head_. Alas, for this aspect, your lab seems decapitated.

Comment: The best advice is probably to find a way to escape this situation.

Comment: Does it mean I should report the aggressor to someone higher? Does it mean I'll have to leave the lab before graduating? I cannot imagine anyone in the lab being happy with the fact that I'm creating problems for their co-worker who doesn't (AFAIK) hurt them.

Comment: It seems that your supervisor does not want to be involved in this matter. How much longer do you have? Do you make progress despite her interference? If so, duck down and finish as soon as you can. German universities do not like to make trouble to their higher-level academics. Are you allowed to use the dictaphone? Then use it. Maybe a subtle way to make her choose her language more carefully. Antibullying mechanisms are not as well established in Germany as in other countries. Is there something you do systematically wrong and can improve? Try to stay out of her limelight if so.

Comment: Depending on where this is in Germany, secret recording would be a very bad idea. Half of Germany had this for about 60 years running. And I don’t think it would go down better in the other half. I’m not sure if a comment suggested this, but just: don’t.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I'm approximately in the middle (1.5/3 years), could be less if we have to extend due to COVID-19. I used to make progress, but I might break down if attacks continue. Yes, I've contacted a professional to treat it. I can get _unpaid_ leave of absence, and job opportunities in a small student town for foreigners with mental health problems aren't plenty.

Comment: @gnometorule, thanks for the warning! What about non-concealed recording, is that also out of question unless all people present explicitly consent to that?

Comment: @user132436 yes, all recording requires consent. And I agree with gnometorule: some people are not only likely to say no, they are also likely to get angry at the mere request...

Comment: @gnometorule I was talking *exclusively* about open recording, hidden recording is illegal in Germany, except for law enforcement and the like. It signals, of course, a complete breakdown of trust. Or try to use email, it's less conspicuous that you keep a record that way.

Comment: I think the most critical thing is: ignoring all the shouting and inappropriate behaviour - would you agree that she is in principle right? Not talking about "but I am doing well enough", but are you doing objectively well or even above average, seen as disinterestedly as you can possibly do it? I think this will inform your further action.

Comment: Re: recording, lesson learned, thanks again. @CaptainEmacs: Objectively, I'm not doing that well, but I'm doing all that is possible in my circumstances.

Comment: @user132436 Ok, if you are in the unenviable position that you do not perform to your bosses' reasonable satisfaction, this makes it essential for you to try to avoid mistakes if at all possible. We all make mistakes, but your direct boss doesn't tolerate them. The best you can do I think is to try and to understand how you can reduce the rate of mistakes. She may not stop screaming, but at least you will know that you are doing your part, which can be oddly reassuring.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that British universities have a duty of care towards all their students and that it is the responsibility of the university to investigate and deal with such issues. Is Germany so different?

Does the university have a postgraduate student support system? You seem to describe a problem that involves staff, supervisor, and you as student. If the issues are not solvable within that departmental group, you are reasonably entitled to ask the the general support system for help. It is not reasonable to expect a PhD student to deal with issues of staff behaviour. You are there to pursue research and it is the duty of the university to support you.

Answer (score 0):

It happens in all kinds of work environments, the only way to conduct yourself is to consider this:

1. you owe her/him no obligations but to be professional;
2. he/she is a human being just like you, so he/she has plenty of vulnerabilities;
3. try to watch for the weaknesses in its compartment, then to leverage with your professionalism and your acknowledgements of his/her weaknesses.

This takes time.

If you will be a good person and not trying to be revengeful this will pay-out in future's work environment's equilibrium.

4. Endure and forgive; all the bad things you are thinking or doing in payback will return to ruin your peace.
5. If anything else doesn't work, man up and confront that dude!